# How many nodes can publish to a single topic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, topic, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello every body. I'm new in Ros and I have a simple question.
How many nodes can publish to a single topic?
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305027/how-many-nodes-can-publish-to-a-single-topic?/) by [hamed ghasemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/37942/hamed-ghasemi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Theoretically? An infinite number of <del>nodes</del> *publishers* can publish to the same topic.

Practically? Until you run out of CPU, memory or network bandwidth. But even then there is no real limit, things will just get really, really, really slow and unreliable.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any number of nodes can publish, as long as the message has the right type.

---

Originally posted by [VictorArias](https://answers.ros.org/users/34179/victorarias/) with karma: 31 on 2018-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3